# What's the ways to send requests to server from HTML5 mobile app?

Tags: android, jquery, angularjs, html, mobile

What's the ways to send requests to server from HTML5 mobile app? I'm using Angularjs and jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Use AngularJS $http method. Its a easy way to communicate with the remote HTTP servers
- [Use this doc.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery ajax calls retrieving JSON data from the server. A few more details in the question would be nice...

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/